# Where does the **kwargs argument comes from the formfield_for_manytomany Django function?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Where does the **kwargs argument comes from for the formfield_for_manytomany Django function?

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "cars":
        kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field,  
    request, **kwargs)
```

kwargs["queryset"]?

Does anybody know?

Comment: not a duplicate the question is where does the **kwargs come from in that function, not what is a **kwrags. this needs good moderation, but judgement on making it duplicate.

Comment: **kwargs is a general argument representing all the keword arguments in a python function. For example in your case the function has a keyword argument as 'queryset'.